# Install brother dcp195c, receiving data but nothing happens, why?

Tags: printing

Can someone please help me to install brother dcp195c drivers on Ubuntu v12?  Using the default driver, the printer says that it is receiving data but nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since this was asked, but I just had to solve this myself (I got to this page after googling around, I'm leaving this answer for everyone who comes here with similar problems). This solution is tested and working fine on Ubuntu 12.04 with Brother DCP-195C (though I'm figuring it will work for similar cases as well).

The [Brother Solution Center](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html) has linux drivers for almost every printer, and, yes, [one for DCP-195C](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-195C). You simply download it (`.deb` for ubuntu, `rpm` for red hat), and install (I tried installing the `cupswrappper` because I read about [someone else](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1756344) who did too, but I have no idea what's better). The Ubuntu Software Center will alert you the installation is this and that. Just tell it to ignore and install anyway.

Then:

1. go to System Settings > Printing > Add.
2. After connecting the printer you should see it listed as a device. Choose it and click Forward
3. It will try auto-searching for drivers, ignore the recommendation below and choose `'Provide PPD file'`.
4. If installed correctly, the relevant ppd file should be in `/usr/share/cups/model/Brother`. Find it and supply it.
5. That's it! Print a test file to be sure

This worked for me! Hope it helps others as well =]

**update 08/2014**

Brother now provides a generic script to install its drivers. It's actually quite impressive, simply [download it and follow the instructions](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp195c_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625). You can also manually download the `.deb` files from [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp195c_all&os=128)

Answer (score 1):

The first place to look when investigating Linux Printer Support is always the [OpenPrinting Homepage](http://www.openprinting.org/printers).

Unfortunately it doesn't contain any information about your printer, but selecting a similar printer from Brother, you can find [this link](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-195C) which contains a driver and installation instructions for your printer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem. When you installed the LPR driver did you get an error about a directory not existing in `spool`?

```
# sudo dpkg -i --force-depends dcp195clpr-1.1.3-1.i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 832663 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace dcp195clpr:i386 1.1.3-1 (using dcp195clpr-1.1.3-1.i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dcp195clpr:i386 ...
Setting up dcp195clpr:i386 (1.1.3-1) ...
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/spool/lpd/dcp195c': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access `/var/spool/lpd/dcp195c': No such file or directory
chgrp: cannot access `/var/spool/lpd/dcp195c': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/var/spool/lpd/dcp195c': No such file or directory
```

This is where it will spool data and thus fail if the directory is not there. Run the following command and then the `dpkg` command again:

```
# sudo mkdir /var/spool/lpd
```

I did this then printed a test page and it came out fine.

*I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. Using KDE.*